# Manga where protagonist is kicked out of the party and becomes a city guard

Tags: story-identification, manga

It's one of those series where the MC is unjustly kicked out of his party, but here he retires and gets a job as a city guard. I've forgotten the title and have been trying to find it for a long time.

It is not *Labyrinth Raids of the Ultimate Tank*, I thought it was, but it is not what I'm looking for.

It is a setting with monsters, magic, and job classes. The MC is your standard aloof black haired protagonist. His old party leader used a spear, was an arrogant jerk, and replaced him with a woman. The entire party was based around offense with no defense and quickly find themselves doing terribly without the MC. In one of the early chapters, he is tested by defending some kind of orb from three other guards who are jerks themselves. And the images are black and white.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about *[Sono Monban, Saikyou Nitsuki: Tsuihou Sareta Bougyo Ryoku 9999 no Senshi, Outo no Monban Toshite Musou Suru](https://www.novelupdates.com/series/the-strongest-gatekeeper-the-expelled-warrior-with-9999-defense-is-unmatched-as-the-gatekeeper-of-the-royal-capital/)*, aka *The Strongest Gatekeeper – The Expelled Warrior With 9999 Defense Is Unmatched As The Gatekeeper Of The Royal Capital*?

> Sieg is an adventurer with incredible defensive power, and he always uses himself to attract the monsters’ attention to assist his teammates. However, the party leader just focused on offense without realizing Sieg’s intention, so he kicked him out. After Sieg left, the team repeatedly failed multiple quests … At the same time, Sieg took the position of the gatekeeper at the Royal Capital. Thanks to his defensive power, he was quickly promoted to division captain. His subordinates included a carefree big-breasted Swordswoman, a perverse freakish girl, and an Archer with an erratic temperament. He and the girls started slowly gaining the trust of the people around them!

A search for `manga "kicked * party" guard` led me to [this Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/manga/comments/mb60rx/manga_about_mc_being_kicked_out_of_his_party_and/).

In both the novel and the webcomic, his test involves protecting a balloon (the translation I've found for the manga calls it a "ball", but it looks more like a balloon to me) from three attacking guards (later the rest of the guard, then the captain who has Skills), who indeed do come off as jerks at first. Moreover, the Royal Capital is a target precisely due to a magic orb housed there. I can't tell if the leader of his party is wielding a spear or a sword, but the protagonist does have black hair.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I've been looking for.

Answer (score 3):

As per [this Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/manga/comments/o471lo/looking_for_a_specific_semi_recent_manga/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3), this may be *[The Labyrinth Raids of the Ultimate Tank ~The Tank Possessing a Rare 9,999 Endurance Skill was Expelled from the Hero Party~](https://myanimelist.net/manga/119811/Saikyou_Tank_no_Meikyuu_Kouryaku__Tairyoku_9999_no_Rare_Skill-mochi_Tank_Yuusha_Party_wo_Tsuihou_sareru)*

The Reddit question:

> I recently found a manga set in a fantasy world(not isekai) where the mc is a tank of the party but got kicked out cuz he was not dealing damage. Which the mc later went ok and left them nd he was hired as a city guard of sorts?

The summary on MyAnimeList:

> Rude is a tank, known as the strongest in history. However, the Hero decided that his skills were worthless because he couldn't do anything but take damage, and threw him out of the party. His cleric friend who trusted him followed him to the remote village that Rude was forced to return to.

Found with a search for `manga kicked out "city guard"`